# How does mathematica integrate around points where the integrand evaluates to ''indeterminate?''

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am interested in studying a numerical integral where the integrand, when evaluated naively at some points in the domain of integration, is indeterminate. However, when one carefully takes limits to these points, the integrand turns out to be finite. Since my actual integrand is multi-dimensional and complicated, let me pose my question in the context of a simple example instead. If I ask mathematica to evaluate $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0$, it says it's indeterminate (although we know that the actual value as $x \to 0$ is finite). However, if I evaluate the numerical integral of this function from $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, it gives me the right result, i.e, a value that matches the result of analytic integration.

**So my question is**: in numerical integration, how does mathematica deal with points where if you ask mathematica to evaluate the integrand, it gives ''indeterminate.'' Are these points omitted? If not, how are they accounted for? In the example above, mathematica was somehow able to deal with $x=0$ correctly when integrating numerically even though it said that the function evaluated at $x=0$ was indeterminate.

Comment: It seems to replace `Indeterminate` at `x == 0` by `0.`.  Successive refinement will diminish the error, and error estimate likely overestimates the actual error due to the discontinuous adjustment.  Of course, a lot of the time `x == 0` won't even be used, and since the discontinuity of $(\sin x)/x$ is removable, the integral will be found quickly and accurately.

Comment: Hmm, ``NIntegrate[Sin[x]/x, {x, -1, 0}, Method -> {"NewtonCotesRule", "Type" -> Closed}, IntegrationMonitor :> ((Sow[AssociationThread[Through[#@"Boundaries"] -> Through[#@"Error"]]]) &), PrecisionGoal -> 6] // Reap // Last // Last // Column`` does something interesting at the sixth step, that must be some sort of singularity processing. Yep, it changes with `"SingularityDepth" -> 1`, for example.

Comment: @MichaelE2, what do you mean when you say it changes?

Comment: I mean get these different outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6HVd.png -- Both results are within the precision goal of the result (not shown).