# NIntegrate fails to give non-numerical value error, instead returns zero

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

When I evaluate

`NIntegrate[a(x - y)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]`

Mathematica returns `0` without giving a non-numerical value error,  despite that fact that there is an undefined `a` in the integrand. If I get rid of the AccuracyGoal specification then the expected error is raised. It is also raised if I multiply `a` by pretty much any function other than `(x-y)^2`.

I'm wondering why, in the particular instance describe above, NIntegrate does not warn me that I'm using incorrect syntax.

EDIT: Using evaluation monitor

`Reap[NIntegrate[a (x - y)^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]`

results in

`{0., {{{0., 0.}, {0.948683,  0.948683}, {-0.948683, -0.948683}, {-0.688247, -0.688247}, {0.688247, 0.688247}}}}`.

This explains why no error was given: NIntegrate evaluates the integrand only at points where it evaluates to the *nonsymbolic* value zero. I suppose my remaining question is why NIntegrate only evaluated the integrand at those points? If I do the same with an explicit value for `a` (say `1`) I find

`Reap[NIntegrate[1 (x - y)^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]`

`{2.66667, {{{0., 0.}, {0.358569, 0.}, {-0.358569, 0.}, {0.948683, 0.}, {-0.948683, 0.}, {0., 0.358569}, {0., -0.358569}, {0., 0.948683}, {0., -0.948683}, {0.948683, 0.948683}, {0.948683, -0.948683}, {-0.948683, -0.948683},{-0.948683, 0.948683}, {-0.688247, -0.688247}, {-0.688247,0.688247}, {0.688247, -0.688247}, {0.688247, 0.688247}}}}`

in disagreement with the case where `a` is symbolic.

Comment: This is weird. It happens only when the ```AccuracyGoal``` is less then infinite.

Comment: These kind of situations are fairly well explained in [`NIntegrate`'s advanced documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html). See, for example, ["Examples of Pathological Behavior"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#8354729).

Comment: @AntonAntonov, I'm not sure that section is directly relevant to my issue. To clarify, I'm wondering why, in this particular case, Mathematica fails to warn me that I'm using incorrect syntax. I'll edit my question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @DeadlosZ I'm finding that the expected error is raised as long as the AccuracyGoal is at least 324. Is the behavior really different on your machine?

Comment: @justacalculator The limit is `ag = -Log10[$MinMachineNumber/2^52] + Log10[2]`, a double-precision floating-point limit.

Comment: `NIntegrate` treats nonnumeric results as singularities and they are discarded.  If there are numeric function values, it assumes that the singularities will be handled in the course of refinement.  In this case because of the symmetry, the error estimate is `0.` and the integration stops. Try `ii[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (Sow[{x, y}, "xy"];
   a (x - y)^2);
NIntegrate[ii[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 8] // Reap` to see the integrand is actually evaluated throughout the domain.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Amazing, thanks! It makes perfect sense now. I did not realize non-numeric results are treated as singularities. Can I ask where you learned that?

As a followup question, what happens when the AccuracyGoal is increased above the limit in your previous comment?

Comment: You said, "I'm finding that the expected error is raised as long as the AccuracyGoal is at least 324." The number `ag` is around `324`. Any `AccuracyGoal` greater than this and you get the expect error.  It's the same number as `Accuracy[0.]`, which is probably a better way to define `ag`, but I didn't think of it at first. - I found out about singularities by reading the docs and experimenting, most recently [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238750)

Comment: To clarify, why does pushing AccuracyGoal above ```ag``` cause the error message to reappear? If I sow and reap the actual values at which the integrand is evaluated, even for AccuracyGoal above ```ag``` I find that the integrand is evaluated at some symmetric points where it is non-symbolic.

Comment: The initial error is `0.` and `Accuracy[0.]` is almost `324`. Ignoring `PrecisionGoal` for now, if you set `AccuracyGoal` higher than `Accuracy[error]`, `NIntegrate` will subdivide the region with the largest error (which at the first step is the whole domain). As subdivision goes on, not all of the new regions will be symmetric with respect to the integrand and two things can happen: The error is no longer zero on a subregion, or the integrand is nonnumeric on the entire subregion. In the first case you get more subdivision. In the second, you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIntegrate treats nonnumeric results as singularities and they are discarded. If there are numeric function values, it assumes that the singularities will be handled in the course of refinement.  If there are no numeric function values at all sampling points, you get a `NIntegrate::inumr` error.

Try the following to see the integrand is actually evaluated throughout the domain.

```
ii[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (Sow[{x, y}, "All"]; a (x - y)^2);
Reap[
   NIntegrate[
    ii[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
    AccuracyGoal -> 8,
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}, "Used"]],
   {"All", "Used"}
   ][[2, All, 1]] // 
 ListPlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"All", "Used"}] &
```

> [image]

Since only points with `x == y` are used, the integral and error are both `0.`:

```
NIntegrate[a (x - y)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, 
  IntegrationMonitor :> (Sow[Through[#@"Error"]] &)] // Reap
```

> ```
> (*  {0., {{{0.}}}}  *)
> ```

The OP observes that an error message does not appear until `AccuracyGoal` is at least `324`.
The actual limit is connected to the smallest (subnormal) machine-precision number, which is the same as `Accuracy[0.]`, accuracy of the error:

```
ag = -Log10[$MinMachineNumber] + Log10[2^53]
Accuracy[0.]
```

> ```
> (*
>   323.607
>   323.607
> *)
> ```

```
NIntegrate[a (x - y)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> (1 - $MachineEpsilon/2) ag]  (* no error *)
```

> ```
> (*  0.  *)
> ```

```
NIntegrate[a (x - y)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> ag]                          (*  error   *)
```

> `NIntegrate::inumr`:  The integrand `a (x-y)^2` has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries `{{0,0.5},{0,1}}`. >>

Ignoring `PrecisionGoal` for this case, if you set `AccuracyGoal` higher than the `Accuracy` of the error, `NIntegrate` will subdivide the region with the largest error (which at the first step is the whole domain). As subdivision goes on, not all of the new regions will be symmetric with respect to the integrand and two things can happen: The integrand is nonnumeric on the entire subregion, or the error is at best `0.` on a subregion. If the first happens, you get a `NIntegrate::inumr` error and integration stops.  In the second, you get more subdivision.